# Turning hsva() data into UIColor in swift 2

Tags: ios, regex

I am trying to use the spectrum javascript plugin as a colour picker for a website I have created to create UIColor objects inside an iOS app I am making.

Spectrum is a handy little color picker:
https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/

which can create colo[u]r codes in rgb/hex/hsv etc. But I want to use the Alpha as well - so I am limited to using either hsva or rgba

Spectrum will give any of these as outputs - which will then be sent via JSON to my app - the 'a' will **only** be shown if I set a transparency in the color picker

hsva(325, 28%, 19%, 0.68)
hsv(325, 28%, 19%)

rgba(255, 69, 0, 0.5)
rgb(255, 69, 0)

how can I parse the data and create a UIColor using the correct init method when I am not sure whether to expect the alpha component?

I was thinking I could use an NSSCanner, but according to a description I read Regex might be a better option as the input is well known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So having played with a few ideas I have gone down this path - match the first chracter/s with the expected formats using a convenience function to self initialize a color

I am posting this as an answer to get feedback on this particular method - I think there is a better method around I am just not knowledgable enough to discover.

```
func CGFloatValue(value: String) -> CGFloat {
guard let doubleValue = Double(value) else {
    return CGFloat(0)
}
return CGFloat(doubleValue)
}
extension UIColor {

convenience init(unknownValue: String) {
    var colorType, colorValue : String

    if unknownValue.hasPrefix("#") {
        //value is hex
        colorType="hex"
        colorValue=String(unknownValue.characters.dropFirst())
    }
    else {
        let result = unknownValue.componentsSeparatedByString("(")
        colorType = result[0]
        colorValue = String(result[1].characters.dropLast())
    }

    print(colorType,colorValue)
    let inputs = colorValue.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet())

    switch(colorType) {
        case "hsva":
        self.init(hue: CGFloatValue(inputs[0]), saturation: CGFloatValue(inputs[1]), brightness: CGFloatValue(inputs[2]), alpha: CGFloatValue(inputs[3]))
            break;
        case "hex":
            //this will be more complicated and based on hackingwithswift hex to uicolor article

            //self.init(red:CGFloat((colour >> 24) & 0xff) / 255, green:CGFloat((colour >> 16) & 0xff)/ 255,blue:CGFloat(((colour >> 8) & 0xff))/ 255,alpha: CGFloat(colour & 0xff)) / 255
        fallthrough
    default:
        //return a default color?
        self.init(red: 255.0,green: 255.0,blue: 255.0,alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

}